# CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion and UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

So after much trial and error and reading Apples documents and SO threads I thought I had my didEnterRegion working properly.

This is what I finished up with...

```
- (void)locationManager:(LocationManager *)locationManager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

NSLog(@"Location manager did enter region called");
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive) {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"You are about to arrive";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Open";
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

} else {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"App Running in foreground notification fired");

        [self setupAlarmTriggeredView];

        //vibrate device
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    });
}
```

}

As you can see it does a simple check to see if the app is active, if not it sets up a UILocalNotification which it presents immediately, if it is it just vibrates and changes the view.

When testing on the simulator using a GPX file to move the location over the boundary, both scenarios work perfectly. However when testing the app out and about, when the app is in the background the notification doesn't seem to fire until you wake the device. ie. you can cross the boundary and nothing happens, then when you unlock the device, boom, it vibrates and the view is changed accordingly. (if the app is not foremost when you unlock this doesn't happen until you re-launch the app).

Should I be doing this setup in appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions? In my testing both that method and didRecieveLocalNotification: in the app delegate don't get called until 'after' the notification has been fired AND the user has re-launched the app by actioning the notification (at which point you can check the for the launch key in the options array), this doesn't seem to be of any use for the initial firing of the notification as part of  didEnterRegion. At the moment I have no code in either of these methods.

As far as I'm aware I don't need to be doing any background location updates for didEnterRegion, this is handled automatically by iOS.

Comment: I guess you need to register your app for running in background. Did you try adding UIBackgroundModes key in your info.plist and resister it for using location services?

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to add I've also done that, well Ive added 'app registers for location updates' under the 'required background modes' key. I'm also running normal location updates as part of updating a distance counter using a timer every 15 seconds. In the simulator when you  tap the home button to exit the app, location updates stop being received, I presume this is normal behaviour.

Comment: Hey Ash same here with my Application. Have you found a solution for this?